# Carbon::parse("25/10/1980") throws an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm facing an odd issue, `Carbon::parse("25/10/1980")` throws the following error:

> Exception with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time
>   string (25/12/1980) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character'

While having **no problems** whatsoever, **if month (10) is swapped places with day (25)** like this:

```
Carbon::parse("10/25/1980")
```

How should I parse the `"d/m/Y"` string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '25/10/1980');
```

Answer (score 3):

This also works (dashes, not slashes)

```
Carbon::parse ('25-10-1980');
```